# Wait for a specific result from Task then run another method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await, task

I have a WPF app running on .net 6 and an external device connected to it.

Initializing the device sometimes fails and I don't want to hold the UI thread trying to initialize it.

I want to run the following method (_device.Init()) in an async fashion and when it returns true, run Start() method.

*edit: run it until it returns true from the _device.Init() method, not true for finishing the task*

Is there a built-in functionality to do it with tasks? or any other "best practice" way?

Thank you :)

```
SomeDevice _device = new();

public async void Init()
{
    // some other code

    while (Task.Run(() => _device.Init()).Result == false)
    {

    }

    Start();
}


public void Start()
{
    // some other code

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                                                          {
                                                              _device.Start();
                                                          }));
}
```

Comment: `async void` is almost always a bad and dangerous idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting the `Result` of the Task (which may block the UI thread) you should `await` the Task:

```
public async void Init()
{
    // some other code

    while (!await Task.Run(() => _device.Init()))
    {
    }

    Start();
}
```

The method should also be awaitable and be awaited when called, e.g. in an async Loaded event handler:

```
public async Task Init()
{
    // some other code

    while (!await Task.Run(() => _device.Init()))
    {
    }

    Start();
}

...
await Init();
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that .Result causes thread blocking?

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin Yes, you are.

Answer (score 1):

```
public async void Init()
{
    var task = _device.Init();

    //do work here

    await task;

    Start();
}
```

Should do the trick, it'll do the work and then wait for the task to complete before going to `Start();`

If you want to simply wait for init to finish and then run start it's even simpler with

```
await _device.Init().ContinueWith((x) => { Start();})
```